# Vector Spaces and Groups

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, vector-spaces

I've just completed a course in linear algebra. I'm a physics undergraduate and I don't plan on taking an abstract algebra course. That said, I've been reading a little bit about it.

As I understand it, a vector space over a field F is a set V along with two operations, scalar multiplication (*) and vector addition (+), that satisfy the following conditions:

1. Associativity of vector addition ... $u + (v + w) = (u + v) + w$
2. Commutativity of vector addition ... $u + v = v + u$
3. Identity element of vector addition ... $u + 0 = u$
4. Inverse element of vector addition ... $u + (-u) = 0$
5. Identity element of scalar multiplication ...$ 1*u = u$
6. Distributivity of scalar multiplication ... $a*(u + v) = a*u + a*v$
7. Closure ... If $u, v$ are in $V$, $c*u + d*v$ is also in $V$.

A group is a set $G$ along with an operation $(*)$ satisfying the following:

1. Closure ... If $g, h$ are in $G$, then $g * h$ is also in $G$.
2. Associativity ... $(g * h) * j = g * (h * j)$
3. Identity element ... $g * e = e * g = g$
4. For each $g$ in $G$, there exists $h$ such that $g * h = e$.

I have a few of questions:

1. Are my definitions of vector spaces and groups correct?
2. What's the key difference between vector spaces and groups? They seem very similar to me.
3. I was told by my linear algebra professor that it's only a convenience to think of vectors as arrows in R^3 with a direction and magnitude. He said that vectors are a much more abstract and general concept. What then are vectors, really?
4. Are there any sets that are both a vector space and a group?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: A vector space is an abelian group with an action by a field. So every vector space is also a group. But not every group can be a vector space, for example if it is not abelian.

Comment: You're going to need, **at least**, some reasonably advanced linear algebra and some Lie Groups theory in physics later, so you deciding not to take abstract algebra could be a bad idea. In my university, it was compulsory for physics student to take at least a basic course in group and ring theory.

Comment: (3) Is the hard question, because there are lots of uses of vector spaces in quite a few cases. It's a generalization which simply crops up enough in mathematics to call them the same thing, and study them, but it is hard to give a visual sense of what is going on, since some fields don't have a visual intuition.

Comment: @Timbuc Thanks for the advice. At my university (University of Illinois at Urbana-Champaign) it's not compulsory for physics students to take abstract algebra. It is, however, compulsory for us to take linear algebra and complex analysis. The rest is up to us what we take.

Comment: No, not all abelian groups are vector spaces. The integers are an abelian group, but are not a vector space.

Comment: Timbuc's advice is not about compulsory, it is about what you want to do if you want to study physics. :)

Comment: A vector space is not just a special kind of group. The action of the scalar field is an additional structure. Not every abelian group can be a vector space. However if you alter the definition slightly, you get a closely related thing called a module. A module is an abelian group with an action of a ring. Basically it's a vector space where you can't divide by scalars. Every abelian group is canonically a module over the ring of integers.

Comment: @Cody, according to my friends (the best of which are **all** physicists), there's no way through theory of elementary particles without Lie Groups...but as Thomas mentioned: my comment wasn't about compulsory but about what will you need to cope with your studies.

Comment: @Timbuc Thanks again. I wonder why it's not compulsory at my university if it's so important to understand upper-level physics. A have a few friends that are physics majors at other universities and abstract algebra isn't compulsory for them either. Maybe that needs to change?

Comment: @ziggurism I see. With a vector space you have the field F and the space V. With a group you only have the set G. Is that what you're saying is the primary difference?

Comment: Note when people say vector spaces are abelian groups, they mean with the operator $+$. The operator name in group theory tends to use multiplication symbols as operators ($*$, $\cdot$, etc.,) because groups cam be non-commutative, and $+$ is usuallycommutative.)

Comment: @Cody I can't tell. I'm at grad school in mathematics and I only know when my physicist friends approached me with tears in their eyes asking for help to understand something in linear operators theory (linear algebra) and Lie Groups (particular groups of matrices). Perhaps the course  in your university include a quicky introduction to these things just to be able to work with them.

Comment: @Cody: that's the difference between *abelian* groups and vector spaces. The difference between abelian groups and all groups is quite large. Abelian groups of course are of course a special kind of group.

Comment: @Timbuc: agree that abstract algebra is necessary for physics eventually. But at the graduate level mostly. An undergraduate in physics can probably sneak by without it. Though I would agree that it would be beneficial.

Comment: @Cody: my favorite abstract algebra text is probably Jacobson. A lot of people like Lang. Dummit and foote for a more elementary choice. But those are all mathematics textbooks. For physicists there's georgi and Glashow and cornwall. I'd start with georgi probably.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Yes. But you don't need to add closure in these definitions For groups, for example, notice that an operation is, first of all, a function $\cdot :G \times G \to G$. And that its codomain is $G$ itself.
2. A vector space is a $4-$tuple $(\mathcal{V},{\Bbb K}, +, \cdot)$, where $$+: \mathcal{V}^2 \to \mathcal{V} \quad \text{and} \quad\cdot:\mathbb{K} \times \mathcal{V} \to \mathcal{V}$$ are the operations. The structure of a vector space is much richer than that of a group. A vector space has two operations and a underlying a field, while a group is only the set with one operation (satisfying conditions you well know). Given a vector space $(\mathcal{V},{\Bbb K}, +, \cdot)$, $(\mathcal{V},+)$ is an abelian group, always. Answering 4. along, given a field $\Bbb K$, $\Bbb K^n$ is both a vector field and an additive group, with respect to the operations of $\Bbb K$.
3. Vectors are elements of a vector space. It is just a name. Examples of vector spaces are:

   - Polynomials with degree less or equal to $n$, with real coefficients: $\mathcal{P}_n(\Bbb R)$.
   - All continuous functions from $[0,1]$ to $\Bbb R$: $\mathscr{C}^0([0,1],\Bbb R)$
   - $\Bbb R^n$ itself.
   - Matrices with real coefficients: $\mathbb{M}_{n \times m}(\Bbb R)$.

and a lot more stuff. I used $\Bbb R$ for concreteness, in general you can take an arbitrary field (for polynomials, matrices, etc). So a vector can be an arrow, a function, a polynomial, a matrix...